# How to query a string with hashtag in mysql

Tags: python, mysql, sql, flask

I want to pass the title of the book as a parameter and get recommendations for the book

```
@app.route('/book_details/<book_title>')
def book_details(book_title):
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
    title = book_title.replace("'", "\\'")
    title = title.replace("&", "\\&")
    title = title.replace("#", "\\#")
    resultValue = cur.execute(f"SELECT * FROM `books` WHERE title = '{title}' LIMIT 1")
    if resultValue > 0:
        rec_book_list = output_recommendations(book_title)
        book = cur.fetchall()
        return render_template('testDetails.html', book = book, book_list = rec_book_list)
    return 'No book'
```

this works well for book titles with single quotes, ampersands but do not work if the book title contains hashtag (#). the function returns 'No book' if there is a # in the title.

How do I query a string with # in it?

Comment: I would remove all the escaping code and let the connector do it: `cur.execute("SELECT * FROM `books` WHERE title = %s LIMIT 1", (title,))`.

Comment: Tried this. Works for  every special character except hashtag (#)

Comment: I found a solution. Instead of passing hashtag (#) and other special characters as they are, passing URL encode of the characters works